# Bookdown stand alone gitbook with separate pages

Tags: markdown, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm not sure if bookdown supports what I'm looking for as I am unable to find out how to do it. I would like to create a gitbook format as a standalone html file, but I want each chapter/section to be it's own page rather than it creating one very long page.

Take the following code:

````
---
title: "A Book"
author: "nook"
documentclass: krantz
output:
  bookdown::gitbook:
    split_by: none
    self_contained: true
    keep_md: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Hello World

Hi.

Bye.

# Hello World 2

Hi.

Bye.
````

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

This is specified by the argument `split_by` in the YAML header of the document which you have set to `none`: `split_by: none` results in a single HTML file. In order to split the document by Chapter (first-level headings, i.e, lines starting with a `#`) you have to set `split_by: chapter`. So the document header should look like this:

```
---
title: "A Book"
author: "nook"
documentclass: krantz
output:
  bookdown::gitbook:
    split_by: chapter
    self_contained: true
    keep_md: true
---
```

See the [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html#gitbook-style) of the bookdown package for further options.